# The import com.google.android.gms.gcm cannot be resolved, Google Play Services already installed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

First of all, I'm using Eclipse.

I just copied this android working project from my other computer (which is now not available) and I'm getting alot of those errors:

**"The import com.google.android.gms.gcm cannot be resolved"**

when trying to do things like:

```
import import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
```

although my Google Play Services is already installed on the SDK Manager, and I added the **google-play-services_lib** library on the workspace and even added Library reference.

after all that I'm still getting those errors.

I installed the Google Play Services version 19.

can you please advise?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no gcm.jar for Google Play Services' GCM.

Comment: OK I just figured out I didn't used it also in the old computer.. But still getting these errors

Answer (score 2):

Hover your mouse over the *com.google.android.gms* import that can not be resolved and towards the bottom of the popup menu, select the **Fix project setup**... option as below. Then it'll prompt to import the google play services library. Select that and you should be good to go.

Comment: When I click on Fix Project Setup it shows No proposals have been found window...

Comment: I saw the same thing as @anju. Still attempting to resolve.